# binding form to input custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**The case** :

I have this custom directive which draws input fields based on the type sent to it.

I would like to add the error messages along with these input fields so that we show the suitable error message. But since the directive doesn't see the form from inside, I am binding the form itself by passing it as parameter.

How can I move from there so I can add some error message like this?

```
<span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
```

Right now all my tries are failing

**JS**

```
 app.directive('customDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope   : {
        type : '=' ,
        name : "="
        form:'='
        } ,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(function () {
                        return scope.type ;
                }, function() {

                    var html = '<input type="'+scope.type+'" name="{{name}}" required>';

                    element.html(html);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
                );
            } 
        } 
});
```

Comment: Are you tring to add validations on form???

Comment: Use '@' in place of '=' because it will take only number if you will write'='

Comment: What are you trying to do??? Why not use a template with conditional show/hide or ng-if etc.

Comment: @ShubhamNigam yes i am trying to add validation to a directive that draws elements ... yes u are right about the params but can you help me with validation ?

Comment: @SidharthPanwar , i want to add validation ... my directive has many types and i have alot of logic in it .. i have a date picker and price ranges and so on ... just can we stick to the current case i mentioned please ?

Comment: can you provide html code .. so that I could be able to understand the structure better

Comment: Have you tried this:
var html = '<input type="'+scope.type+'" name="{{name}}" required><span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">';

Comment: Another this is that you can't use myForm.input because the name of your input control is dynamic. You should either keep it static or change it in the ng-show condition as well.